# iPhone app update pending developer release - how long between release and appearing in the store?

Tags: iphone, ios, store

Not sure if this is an appropriate forum to ask as this isn't really a technical question, but...

I have several existing applications on the iOS App Store that I've submitted updates to, and they've all been approved and are now in the 'waiting for developer release' state: basically I click a button and they should be released to the store.  However, I also have a new app that's been approved that will be going on sale in a few days (configured via the Rights & Pricing tab), and I'd like to have the update releases to the public coincide with the new app.. does anyone know the approximate turnaround time between releasing the update as the developer and when it will appear on the store?

The last official document I remember reading suggested there'd be around a 24 hour waiting period, but I'm wondering if anyone has any more experience as to the exact delay.. I'm considering maybe approving them midday or early evening the day before I want them to appear, in the hopes that the delay is actually less than 24 hours and they'll appear in the morning on the designated day.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You're over thinking this. Submit as soon as you can, and get it out there. It's never going to be "morning" in most timezones, regardless of when you submit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience the delay has been considerably less than 24 hours. I've downloaded an app via the App Store within an hour of pressing the button in the past.